# Css момощь nth-child

Tags: css

Есть такое меню, прописал я

```
#header .top-menu ul li a:hover {color:#4a4a4a;}
```

и все ссылки меняют цвет при наведении как сделать что только ссылка ***4*** и ссылка ***1*** меняла цвет при наведении мышки ?

```html
<li><a href="#"><b>Ссылка 1</b></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><b>Ссылка 2</b></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><b>Ссылка 3</b></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><b>Ссылка 4</b></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка подменю 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка подменю 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка подменю 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка подменю 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: а если больше четырех ссылок - тоже четвертая? Или все же имелось в виду первая и последняя?

Comment: Сергей, все равно четвертая)

Answer (score 2):

Решение в лоб:

```css
#header .top-menu ul li:first-child:hover a,
#header .top-menu ul li:nth-child(4):hover a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="top-menu">
    <li><a href="#"><b>Ссылка 1</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><b>Ссылка 2</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><b>Ссылка 3</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><b>Ссылка 4</b></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Ссылка подменю 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ссылка подменю 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ссылка подменю 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ссылка подменю 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

[first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) - `:first-child` находит любой элемент, являющийся первым в своём родителе.

[nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) - `:nth-child` находит один или более элементов, основываясь на их позиции среди группы соседних элементов.

Если всё же имелось в виду первый и последний элемент:

```css
#header .top-menu ul li:first-child:hover a,
#header .top-menu ul li:last-child:hover a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="top-menu">
    <li><a href="#"><b>Ссылка 1</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><b>Ссылка 2</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><b>Ссылка 3</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><b>Ссылка 4</b></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Ссылка подменю 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ссылка подменю 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ссылка подменю 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ссылка подменю 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

[last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) - `:last-child`  находит любой элемент, являющийся последним в его родителе.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#header .top-menu ul>li:nth-child(3n+1)>a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="top-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><b>Ссылка 1</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><b>Ссылка 2</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><b>Ссылка 3</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><b>Ссылка 4</b></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Ссылка подменю 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ссылка подменю 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ссылка подменю 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ссылка подменю 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```